# Variation of exercise $1.1.1$ from Tao’s measure theory book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $R$ and $S$ be $n-$dimensional boxes. That is $R = I_1 \times I_2 \cdots \times I_n$ and $S = J_1 \times J_2 \cdots \times J_n$.  Show that the difference $R \setminus S$ is a finite union of $n$-dimensional boxes.

This is a slight modification of from Tao’s measure theory book from exercise $1.1.1$ where instead of the elementary set we’re looking at the elements of it. I cannot find any properties for the difference of the products $\prod_k I_k \setminus \prod_k J_k$. The only one I found was (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Difference_of_Cartesian_Products), which isn’t of much help. Is there a way to manipulate $\prod_k I_k \setminus \prod_k J_k$ somehow?

Comment: Is it intersection or union? I think it should be union how can you write "L" shaped object as an intersection of "rectangles"(n-dim boxes). In your reference it is also union of boxes not intersection.

Comment: Union indeed! Corrected the question.

Comment: Then just consider 2 dimensional case. I think you will get the intuition to solve n-dimensional case. Draw some rectangles etc.

Comment: Here is a [picture proof](https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-1-1??utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link) which is not what you are looking for, but formal proof would be similar (that is, case-by-case).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose N = {1,...,n}. So, we have $R \setminus S = R \cap S^c$ and we know that

\begin{equation*}
S^c = \bigcup_{K \subset N : K \neq \emptyset} \prod_{i}^{n} \left( J_i^K \right)
\end{equation*}
where for each $K \subset N$, we define the collection $\{ J_i^K \}$ as

\begin{equation*}
J_i^K = J_i \quad \textrm{if} \quad i \in K , \quad J_i^K = J_i^c \quad \textrm{if} \quad i \notin K
\end{equation*}

Then

\begin{align*}
R \cap S^c &= R \cap \left( \bigcup_{K \subset N : K \neq \emptyset} \prod_{i=1}^{n}  J_i^K \right) \\ &= \bigcup_{K \subset N : K \neq \emptyset} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_i \cap \prod_{i=1}^{n}  J_i^K \right) \\ &= \bigcup_{K \subset N : K \neq \emptyset} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_i \cap J_i^K \right)
\end{align*}

and so we conclude that it is a union of a finite number of boxes.

Comment: Where did the formula for $S^c$ come from?

Comment: @Georgi  $\mathbf{S^c \subset X}$: if $x \notin S$ then there is $K \in N : K \neq \emptyset$ such that $x_i \notin \prod J_i^K$ so it belongs to X. $\mathbf{X \subset S^c}$: if $x \in X$ then there is $K \in N : K \neq \emptyset$ such that $x \in \prod J_i^K$, then because $K \neq \emptyset$ we know that there is $i \in K$ and $x_i \in J_i^K = J_i^c$ so that $x \notin S$. It is a generalization of the much simpler formula for $S = I \times J \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which is $S^c = \left( I^c \times J \right) \cup \left( I \times J^c \right) \cup \left( I^c \times J^c \right)$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The above picture is for $d=2$.

$(I_1\times I_2)\setminus (J_1\times J_2) = [(I_1\setminus J_1)\times I_2]\cup [I_1\times (I_2\setminus J_2)].$
This is a finite union of $2$-dimensional boxes.

$(I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_d)\setminus (J_1\times J_2\times\cdots\times J_d)=[(I_1\setminus J_1)\times I_2\cdots\times I_d]\cup [I_1\times (I_2\setminus J_2)\cdots\times I_d]\cup\cdots\cup [I_1\times I_2\cdots\times (I_d\setminus J_d)].$
This is a finite union of $d$-dimensional boxes.

Proof:
Let $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in (I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_d)\setminus (J_1\times J_2\times\cdots\times J_d).$
Then, $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_d.$
And, $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\notin J_1\times J_2\times\cdots\times J_d.$

$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\notin J_1\times J_2\times\cdots\times J_d$
$\Leftrightarrow$
There exists $i\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$ such that $x_i\notin J_i.$

So,
$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_d$ and $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\notin J_1\times J_2\times\cdots\times J_d.$
$\Leftrightarrow$
$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_d$ and there exists $i\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$ such that $x_i\notin J_i.$
$\Leftrightarrow$
There exists $i\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$ such that $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times (I_i\setminus J_i)\times\cdots\times I_d.$
$\Leftrightarrow$
$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\in [(I_1\setminus J_1)\times I_2\cdots\times I_d]\cup [I_1\times (I_2\setminus J_2)\cdots\times I_d]\cup\cdots\cup [I_1\times I_2\cdots\times (I_d\setminus J_d)].$